# Inefficient layout weight>fix>touch target size too small

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

The problem is on the Line 141

```
1   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
2   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
3       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
4       android:layout_width="match_parent"
5       android:layout_height="match_parent">
6   
7       <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
8           android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
9           android:layout_width="0dp"
10          android:layout_height="0dp"
11          android:background="@drawable/img_bgaccount"
12          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
13          app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.15"
14          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
15          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
16  
17          <ImageView
18              android:id="@+id/imageView"
19              android:layout_width="72dp"
20              android:layout_height="72dp"
21              android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
22              android:contentDescription="@string/uploadDesc"
23              app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
24              app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
25              app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_logoavatar" />
26      </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
27  
28      <ScrollView
29          android:layout_width="0dp"
30          android:layout_height="0dp"
31          android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
32          android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
33          app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
34          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
35          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
36          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout2" >
37  
38          <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
39              android:layout_width="match_parent"
40              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
41  
42              <LinearLayout
43                  android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
44                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
45                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
46                  android:orientation="vertical">
47  
48                  <TextView
49                      android:id="@+id/textViewEmail"
50                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
51                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
52                      android:text="@string/textboxEmail"
53                      android:textColor="@color/color_secondaryred"
54                      android:textSize="18sp"
55                      android:textStyle="bold" />
56  
57                  <EditText
58                      android:id="@+id/textboxInsertEmail"
59                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
60                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
61                      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
62                      android:autofillHints="Masukkan E-mail"
63                      android:background="@drawable/bg_edittextpink"
64                      android:ems="10"
65                      android:importantForAccessibility="no"
66                      android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
67                      android:minHeight="48dp"
68                      android:padding="17dp"
69                      android:text="@string/textboxInsertEmail"
70                      android:textColor="@color/color_passive"
71                      android:textSize="16sp" />
72  
73                  <EditText
74                      android:id="@+id/textboxRepeatEmail"
75                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
76                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
77                      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
78                      android:autofillHints="Masukkan E-mail"
79                      android:background="@drawable/bg_edittextpink"
80                      android:ems="10"
81                      android:importantForAccessibility="no"
82                      android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
83                      android:minHeight="48dp"
84                      android:padding="17dp"
85                      android:text="@string/textboxRepeatEmail"
86                      android:textColor="@color/color_passive"
87                      android:textSize="16sp" />
88  
89                  <LinearLayout
90                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
91                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
92                      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
93                      android:orientation="horizontal">
94  
95                      <TextView
96                          android:id="@+id/textboxOTP"
97                          android:layout_width="72dp"
98                          android:layout_height="48dp"
99                          android:layout_weight="1"
100                         android:background="@drawable/bg_edittextgray"
101                         android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
102                         android:inputType="number"
103                         android:text="@string/textboxOTP"
104                         android:textSize="16sp" />
105 
106                     <Button
107                         android:id="@+id/buttonOTP"
108                         android:layout_width="90dp"
109                         android:layout_height="48dp"
110                         android:layout_marginStart="84dp"
111                         android:layout_weight="1"
112                         android:background="@drawable/bg_btngray"
113                         android:text="@string/buttonViewOTP"
114                         android:textSize="16sp"
115                         app:backgroundTint="@null" />
116 
117                 </LinearLayout>
118             </LinearLayout>
119 
120             <LinearLayout
121                 android:layout_width="0dp"
122                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
123                 android:orientation="vertical"
124                 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
125                 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
126                 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout4">
127 
128                 <TextView
129                     android:id="@+id/textViewFullname"
130                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
131                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
132                     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
133                     android:text="@string/textViewFullname"
134                     android:textColor="@color/color_secondaryred"
135                     android:textSize="18sp"
136                     android:textStyle="bold" />
137 
138                 <EditText
139                     android:id="@+id/editTextTextFullName"
140                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
141                     android:layout_height="48dp"                //this is the problem
142                     android:layout_weight="1"
143                     android:ems="10"
144                     android:hint="@string/hintFullName"
145                     android:importantForAccessibility="no"
146                     android:inputType="textPersonName"
147                     android:text="@string/textViewFullname"
148                     android:textSize="16sp" />
149 
150                 <LinearLayout
151                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
152                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
153                     android:orientation="horizontal">
154 
155                     <EditText
156                         android:id="@+id/textboxGelarDepan"
157                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
158                         android:layout_height="48dp"
159                         android:layout_weight="1"
160                         android:ems="10"
161                         android:hint="@string/hintGelarDepan"
162                         android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
163                         android:text="@string/textViewGelarDepan"
164                         android:textColor="@color/color_passive"
165                         android:textSize="16sp" />
166 
167                     <EditText
168                         android:id="@+id/textboxGelarBelakang"
169                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
170                         android:layout_height="48dp"
171                         android:layout_weight="1"
172                         android:ems="10"
173                         android:hint="@string/hintGelarBelakang"
174                         android:inputType="textPersonName"
175                         android:text="@string/textViewGelarBelakang"
176                         android:textColor="@color/color_passive"
177                         android:textSize="16sp" />
178                 </LinearLayout>
179             </LinearLayout>
180 
181         </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
182     </ScrollView>
183 
184 
185 
186     <LinearLayout
187         android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
188         android:layout_width="0dp"
189         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
190         android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
191         android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
192         android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
193         android:orientation="horizontal"
194         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
195         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
196         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
197 
198         <TextView
199             android:id="@+id/textViewAlreadyHaveAccount"
200             android:layout_width="109dp"
201             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
202             android:layout_weight="1"
203             android:gravity="center|end"
204             android:text="@string/textViewAlreadyHaveAccount"
205             android:textSize="14sp"
206             android:textStyle="bold" />
207 
208         <TextView
209             android:id="@+id/textViewLogin"
210             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
211             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
212             android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
213             android:layout_weight="1"
214             android:gravity="center|start"
215             android:text="@string/textViewLogin"
216             android:textColor="@color/color_secondaryred"
217             android:textSize="16sp"
218             android:textStyle="bold" />
219     </LinearLayout>
220 
221 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I press "Fix" button on android studio or change to 0dp, **Error Message: Touch target size too small.**
Anyone have any idea how to get out from this vicious circle?
what made the error/warning?
is it okay to have "warning message" as long as it is not "error message"?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Any on-screen element that someone can click, touch, or otherwise interact with should be large enough for reliable interaction. Consider making sure these elements have a width and height of at least 48dp.

...

Right fix is adding minHeight or minWith to component as showed below:

[image]

You can find the rest of the article [here](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/7101858?hl=en)

Comment: Please format code as a codeblock, rather than as an image.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding:

```kotlin
android:minHeight="48dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this line

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"   <-----------
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  <-----------
android:layout_gravity="center"       <-----------
android:minWidth="360dp"              <-----------
```

Full Code

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTextFullName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:minWidth="360dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/hintFullName"
    android:importantForAccessibility="no"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/textViewFullname"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```